# How can i upgrade or add new IP for accessing the Order Page using opencart 2.1?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I'm unable to to delete order from admin panel. When i click on delete button for deleting the order then opencart giving me following warning.

```
Warning: Your IP 94.........118 is not allowed to access this API!
```

I'm using Opencart 2.1.0.1 version. Can any one help me regarding this i would like to appreciates.

Comment: Welcome to SO. what have you tried?

Comment: @iam-decoder I tried to add api from admin panel but there is no option.

Answer (score 2):

go to `Admin/System/User/API` edit and under the IP address you can add ip
[image]